# How to put text inside ListItem on the right side?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I have these now, and the "YoYo" text are aligned to the left (as default). And I'd like to control the "YoYo" texts' positions so some of them could appear on the right.

I tried to supply a style object with `justifyContent:'flex-end'` or `alignSelf:'flex-end'` but none of them is working.

```
  <List>
    <ListItem containerElement={<ChatObject id='1' value="YoYo" style={{alignSelf:'flex-end'}} />} />
    <ListItem containerElement={<ChatObject id='1' value="YoYo" />} />
    <ListItem containerElement={<ChatObject id='1' value="YoYo" />} />
    <ListItem containerElement={<ChatObject id='1' value="YoYo" />} />
    <ListItem containerElement={<ChatObject id='1' value="YoYo" />} />
  </List>
```

The `ChatObject` is defined as:

```
render() {
    return (
      <TextField
        id={this.props.id}
        value={this.props.value}
        underlineShow={false}
      />
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I successfully did it with this:

```
<ListItem style={{display:'flex', justifyContent:'flex-end'}} >
  <ChatObject id={item.id} value={item.value} />
</ListItem>
```

The key here is to add `display:'flex'`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I want it for the exact same thing.

Comment: for MUI5 you have to replace "style" with "sx"

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by giving style like

```
  text-align: right;
```

So it will be `textAlign: 'right'` in style object.

Don't forget giving proper width too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<ListItemText />` component which gets props [like "primary" and "secondary"](https://mui.com/api/list-item-text/#props).
You can pass to primary/secondary node element like `<Typography />` that has textAlign property.

```js
<ListItem divider={divider}>
  <ListItemText
    inset
    primary={
      <Paper sx={{ p: 2, backgroundColor: orange[50] }}>
        <Typography noWrap={false} sx={{ wordBreak: 'break-all' }} variant='h5'>
          {item.value}
        </Typography>
      </Paper>
    }
    secondary={
      <Typography textAlign={item.left ? 'left' : 'right'}>
        your text here...
      </Typography>
    }
  />
</ListItem>
```

[image]

Be careful on variant as 'caption' as it will make the text a span element that does not listen to the text-align property.

Answer (score 0):

At first look, you should pass the style props to the sub-element one by one until the DOM element.
For example:`<TextField style={props.style} />`